# How to know what columns are visible whit Kendo Grid MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have a Kendo Grid whit "x" number of columns, but the user can hide the columns and i need know what columns are visible to export data only for these columns, i access to the columns in JS whit

```
var columns = $("#grid").data("kedoGrid");
```

but it returns all columns not only the visibles.
tankz

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just get the list of columns by using this:

```
var columns = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").columns;
```

The result will be **an array of all column objects** which has a property name `hidden: true` for hidden columns by users. In my case it is like following. So simply you will be able to get the visible column list into an array using following code.

```
var visibleColumns = [];
jQuery.each(columns, function (index) {
  if(!this.hidden) {
    visibleColumns.push(this);
  }
});
```

## Hidden Column

```
attributes: Object
encoded: true
field: "pb"
footerAttributes: Object
headerAttributes: Object
hidden: true
title: "Price / Book"
width: 120
__proto__: Object
```

## Visible Column

```
encoded: true
field: "name"
title: "Company Name"
width: 120
__proto__: Object
```

Hope this will help.