# get all column properties of a kendo grid using jquery loop

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Can I possibly get properties of all columns in a Grid like width, encoding, field title etc. The goal is to override the column setting of the grid and to save it on the database.

I want to override this for example:

```
  var columns = new[] 
            {
                new GridColumnSettings
                {
                    Member = "ProductName",
                    Width = "200px"
                },
                new GridColumnSettings
                {
                    Member = "UnitPrice",
                    Width = "130px",
                    Format = "{0:c}",
                },
                new GridColumnSettings
                {
                    Member = "UnitsInStock",
                    Width = "130px"
                },
                new GridColumnSettings
                {
                    Member = "LastSupply",
                    Width = "130px",
                    Format = "{0:d}"
                },
                new GridColumnSettings
                {
                    Member = "Discontinued"
                },
                new GridCommandColumnSettings
                {
                    Commands = 
                    {
                        new GridEditActionCommand(),
                        new GridDestroyActionCommand()
                    },
                    Width = "200px",
                    Title = "Commands"
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the question is not if you can, the question is if you *should*. The answer is no, you should not.

This is something not supported. A grid is a grid and has it own columns, the columns can be hidden or displayed, can be moved, resized... **but** the columns should not be dynamically created. As far as you change the width might be ok, but as soon as you try to change the name it is not because that's actually removing a column and creating another.

So, why do you want to do it? Maybe there is a simpler way of getting the same result.

**EDIT**: If you want to get current column status, you can get them from `grid.columns` array. Where `grid` is the the KendoUI Grid object.

Example:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid")
console.log("Columns", JSON.stringify(grid.columns));
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/emD5t/2/

Comment: just like the column settings, i just want to save the column arrangements, the width of each column

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494158/how-to-know-what-columns-are-visible-whit-kendo-grid-mvc

just like in here i would like to create an array containing all the column properties and load it as the column setting. in short i would like to update the column setting each and every time the user exits. Thanks sir OnaBai

Comment: thanks sir OnaBai, I have already solved my problem, I can now store the grid properties server side. You gave me the idea.. I use ajax to perform save and load properties of the grid as well as paging filters etc. thanks